# Uncaught No script found with scriptLocation in woo-cormmerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Mastercard payment gateway woo commerce plugin, I am using an external JS file, and I am getting an error "Uncaught No script found with scriptLocation 'https://cbcmpgs.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/57/checkout.js'".

This is my code

```
add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'enqueueAssets'));
   
public function enqueueAssets()
{           
  wp_register_script('checkoutwaiting', plugins_url('../js/checkout.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('checkoutwaiting');
}
```

I am using WordPress(6.2.2) and PHP (8.1). I am getting this error in the console during the checkout page loading.

Can you please anyone advise me to fix this issue?

Similar issue - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/uncaught-no-script-found-with-scriptlocation/